# The workplace has invisible upvote and downvote buttons sometimes?

Tags: bug, design, css, voting

I am not a "The workplace stack exchange" user, but I visit it sometimes when there are hot questions from the site on the side bar.

Sometimes I have found that the upvote and downvote buttons do not show up. But I can still click them. I will try to post a image if possible.

Has anyone else seen such behavior?

**EDIT:** I use Firefox 21.0 on my Ubuntu 12.10 computer.

Comment: how exactly are you clicking on the buttons if they don't show up?

Comment: @Sathya By guessing where they should be.Also the mouse pointer changes to hand.

Comment: Are you using google chrome? if so this is a semi known issue

Comment: @RhysW No, I use Firefox 21.0 on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot next time you see this happen? When you click the arrows, does it look like the vote is registered or do you get an error?

Comment: @AnnaLear The votes are always registered.I will try to add a screenshot next time I get this.